# Access Table Header Row Key React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

I was working with tables and I came across this issue: I want to access the `data-row-key` attribute (shown in the image below) in the table header row at a child row and I'm stuck. Code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const columns = [
      // sample of how the JSON API is read
      {
        title: "Title", dataIndex: "title", key: "title",
      },
      // the one that actually matters. becomes the actions column eventually
      {
        title: "Action", dataIndex: "", key: "x", width: "12%",
        render: () => (
          <Popconfirm
            placement="topRight"
            title="Are you sure to delete this task?"
            // retrieve the data here as a parameter into the confirm(n) call
            onConfirm={() => confirm(43)} okText="Yes" cancelText="No"
          >
            <a>delete</a>
          </Popconfirm>
        )
      }
    ];
    return (
      <Table columns={columns} dataSource={this.state.data}/>
    );
  }
}
```

Right now I have the actual number (43) in there, but I want it to be dynamic as to be able to retrieve the data from the `<tr data-row-key=...>` tag, shown in the image below.

As a note, there is not a leading `id` column at the start of the table. The keys are provided through Django's rest framework -- which is in JSON format, in the very last image. Rendered results:
[image]

JSON format:

[image]

Can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `querySelector` for it.

```
let value = document.querySelector('data-row-key')
```

Comment: Where should I put it?

Comment: You can put in anywhere you need. But that method or function have to called only after the initial rendering.

Comment: I used `onConfirm={() => confirm(document.querySelector('data-row-key'))}` but it turned out to be null, so is `document.querySelector('data-row-key')`

Answer (score 0):

To get the data-row-key value call the onclick method with this function:
e.currentTagart.getAttribute("data-row-key")  basically you will have some thing similar to this:

```
<td><i className="fas fa-edit" data-row-key={order.id} onClick={(e)=>getItemKey(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-row-key'))} ></i></td>
```